# Trying to set DHCP IPs and manual DNS server

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, netplan

my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop is connected to a WiFi with DHCP but I want to manual set a unique DNS server into the network.

When I set /etc/resolv.conf with the following configuration it works well, but as you know this settings are temporarily:

```
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
#options edns0
nameserver 192.168.1.50
```

Results:

```
$ nslookup router.home.com
Server:     192.168.1.50
Address:    192.168.1.50#53

Name:   router.home.com
Address: 192.168.1.1
```

To make this settings permanent I found that I can use netplan but didn't work to me as you can see next:

nslookup router.home.com
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53
** server can't find router.home.com: NXDOMAIN

My current configurations are:

```
$ ip addr
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:4e:26:36:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.43/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 84380sec preferred_lft 84380sec
    inet6 fe80::340e:32d:6bf5:a2cc/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Netplan config:

```
$ ls /etc/netplan
01-network-manager-all.yaml

sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: no
      access-points:
    "**SSID**":
      password: "**PASSWORD**"
      nameservers:
    addresses: [192.168.1.50]
```

This was the output applying the changes:

```
$ sudo netplan apply
$ sudo netplan --debug apply
** (generate:12411): DEBUG: 14:56:58.874: Processing input file /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml..
** (generate:12411): DEBUG: 14:56:58.874: starting new processing pass
** (generate:12411): DEBUG: 14:56:58.874: wlp1s0: adding wifi AP '**SSID**'
** (generate:12411): DEBUG: 14:56:58.874: wlp1s0: setting default backend to 2
** (generate:12411): DEBUG: 14:56:58.874: Configuration is valid
** (generate:12411): DEBUG: 14:56:58.874: Generating output files..
** (generate:12411): DEBUG: 14:56:58.874: networkd: definition wlp1s0 is not for us (backend 2)
DEBUG:no netplan generated networkd configuration exists
DEBUG:netplan generated NM configuration changed, restarting NM
DEBUG:wlp1s0 not found in {}
DEBUG:Merged config:
network:
  bonds: {}
  bridges: {}
  ethernets: {}
  vlans: {}
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      access-points:
        **SSID**:
          password: **PASSWORD**
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-dns: false
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.50

DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: lo
DEBUG:Skipping non-physical interface: enp2s1
DEBUG:{}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for enp2s1
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for wlp1s0
```

Testing I could found any change:

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 3 (wlp1s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.1

Link 2 (enp2s1)
      Current Scopes: none
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

Even though I disabled systemd-resolved service, NetworkManager also dynamically modifies the symbolic link resolv.conf, I fixed that with:

```
$ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
```

Editing resolv.conf:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver ::1
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

And I put the overwrite protection flag:
    $ sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf

Permissions:

```
$ ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71 jul 18 17:24 /etc/resolv.conf
    %
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6):

Don't manually edit `/etc/resolv.conf`

Set your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file to...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Edit your wireless connection profile...

- Automatic (DHCP)
- DNS Automatic to OFF
- comma separated DNS servers in the DNS field

[image]

**Update #1:**

You've severely disabled portions of your networking software. You need to put it all back...

- re-enable systemd-resolved
- delete your current /etc/resolv.conf and reset the symlink
- change your /etc/netplan/*.yaml to what I indicate
- undo other changes that you made
- follow my original answer

Comment: Not worked!

`
$ nslookup router.home.com
Server:  127.0.0.53
Address: 127.0.0.53#53

** server can't find router.home.com: NXDOMAIN
`

Comment: @JorgeFernandes your /etc/resolv.conf symlink may be incorrect. Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: The question was updated.

Comment: @JorgeFernandes since you've hacked up your network configuration, there's really nothing more I can do to help you. Sorry.